# Undefined behaviour of program. Sometimes it works, sometimes an error occured while running

Tags: c, malloc

**Please, tell me what is wrong.**

Creating 2d dynamic array:
I've created an array of pointers and then I allocated a block per each pointer.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int **a = NULL;

    a = (int **)malloc(5*sizeof(int *));

    if ( NULL == a)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory.");
        return 1;
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        a[i] = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int ));

    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
            a[i][j] = i*j;
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )           // While running it prints this array. But...
    {                                   
        for ( j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
            printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    /* Trying to free allocated memory. */
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )           // ... sometimes app crashes around here.
    {
        free(a[i]);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Cannot see any reason of such undefined behaviour...

Comment: `malloc(5*sizeof(int *)` -- `for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) a[i] = ...` -- spot a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
a = (int **)malloc(5*sizeof(int *));
```

Creates enough space for 5 pointers to a list of integers

Then you write

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
   a[i] = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int ));
```

Where you are trying to use 10 of them!

Hence undefined behavior. Either change 10 to 5 or allocate the correct amount of space

Answer (score 2):

Ed Heal and Mat show you where the problem is, so let me tell you how to never have this problem again.

## Avoid "Magic Numbers" in your code.

When allocating, put the size in a variable (using the number exactly ONCE), then use that variable wherever you need the size.

```
int an = 5;
a = (int **)malloc(an * sizeof(int *));

...

for ( i = 0; i < an; i++ )
   a[i] = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int ));
```

As Ed reminds me, it doesn't have to be a variable. You could use a preprocessor macro.

```
#define AN 5
```

Or you can also use an `enum`.

```
enum { AN = 5 };
```

These two options are generally better if the number is a constant (variables are for things that vary).

Comment: `#define` would be just as good if it is a constant.